Как открыть веб-сайт по url в окне tkinter в питоне
Я хочу открыть в питоне именно только сайт, а не окно в браузере. С помощью какой библиотек это можно реализовать?

Попробуйте через webview
from tkinter import *
import webview 
  
tk = Tk() 
  
tk.geometry("800x450") 
  
webview.create_window('My webapp', 'https://example.com') 
webview.start() 

